# Drop One Marker at time

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Api v3 and I'm trying to drop one marker at time on my Map, just like [Google Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) but I could not get it to work, here's my code, all markers are dropped at same time.

```
var map;
var markers = [];

function initialize() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);

    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
}

initialize();

function loadMarkers() {  

    $.ajax({
       url: 'js/poi.php',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType : "json",
       success: function (data) {

            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();      


            $.each(data, function(index, point) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Lng),
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: 'img/marker.png'

                });


                markers.push(marker);
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        }

    });
}

loadMarkers();
```

I tried do use a Timeout on each Marker but i guess that loadMarkers(); will always drop them at once...

```
    setTimeout(function() {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Lng),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: 'img/marker.png'

        });

    }, point.Id * 200);
```

Any ideas on how could I fix this ?

**EDIT:** The poi.php file list all points from my Table and Output them like  this:

```
[
{"Id":"1","Lat":"52.511467","Lgn":"13.447179"},
{"Id":"2","Lat":"52.549061","Lgn":"13.422975"},
{"Id":"3","Lat":"52.497622","Lgn":"13.396110"},
{"Id":"4","Lat":"52.517683","Lgn":"13.394393"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially create the marker with these values:

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Lng),
            map: null,
            visible:false
    });
```

set a variable used for the counter for the timeout, and always reset this vaiable when the zoom of the map changes(what forces a re-clustering)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
  this.set('counter',0);
})
```

observe the `map_changed`-event of the markers to  apply the animation when a previous clustered marker has been removed from a cluster

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'map_changed',function(){
      var marker=this,map=this.getMap();
      //the marker has been clustered
      if(!this.getMap()){     
        this.setValues({visible:false});
      }
      //the marker is not a part of a cluster
      else{
        //the marker has been clustered before, set visible and animation with a delay
        if(!this.getVisible()){
            var counter=this.getMap().get('counter')+1;
            //set the new counter-value
            this.getMap().set('counter',counter);
            setTimeout(function(){marker.setValues({animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                                    visible:true});},
                       200*counter)
        }
      }


});
```

Result: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9jaLqpfd/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9jaLqpfd/)

Answer (score 2):

1. add the markers to the clusterer as they are added to the map
2. adjust the bounds to show the markers as they are added
3. fixed typo in your JSON (don't know if that is a problem or not)

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);

    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
    loadMarkers();
}

function loadMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        },
        delay: 3,
        success: function (data) {
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            $.each(data, function (index, point) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Lng),
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        map: map /* don't have your custom marker
                        icon: 'img/marker.png'*/
                      });
                      markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
                      markers.push(marker);
                      // adjust the bounds to show all the markers
                      latlngbounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                      map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
                    }, point.Id * 200);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbLw5qt/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the code, works great if the markers are not clustered.I'm trying to animate only unclustered markers first and then, if the user clicks the markers group, animate markers inside them. I'm afraid that too many marker animations onStart will slow down the site. I'm testing this using your Fiddle, If I fix it I'll post here

Comment: I tried but I could not animate unclustered markers first, and only animate the clustered markers if the user clicks on it. Any help would be great.